# How do I create page navigation linking to each H2 within the page?

Tags: functions, menus, navigation, walker

I require each page on a WordPress site that I'm developing to have page-level navigation linking to each H2 on the page. How do I best automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you a start and you will be able to adjust the code to your requirements.

Add a list `ul` where you want the page level navigation to appear.

```
<ul class='page-nav'></ul>
```

Next, use this JS (requires JQuery) to create the navigation. This code assumes that `<h2>` element do not have `id` attribute set.

```
var idx = 0;

$('h2').each(function() {
    // Get text of h2
    var text = $(this).text();

    // Add id attribute if not set
     $(this).attr('id', 'heading' + idx);

    // Create list item and append to list        
    $('<li/>')
        .append($('<a />', {text: text, href:'#heading' + idx }))
        .appendTo('.page-nav');

    idx++;

});
```

**I have created a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qaisarferoz/zwa8sxqo/5/)**

> How do I best automate this?

You may create a shortcode for it or use your theme files, or it can be used to create a plugin, it depends upon your use case.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: Missing class selector added to code.